# Can a record discriminant determine array lengths indirectly in Ada?

Tags: types, record, ada

I'm trying to account for a special case in which several array lengths should be shorter than normal, but where there's no direct relationship between the discriminant and the array lengths. A simplified record might look like this in the normal case:

```
type Int_Array is array(Integer range <>);

type My_Record is
record
    A : Integer;
    B : Integer;
    C : Int_Array(1..10);
    D : Int_Array(1..6);
end record;
```

But if some discriminant is 320, it should look like this:

```
type My_Record is
record
    A : Integer;
    B : Integer;
    C : Int_Array(1..4);
    D : Int_Array(1..2);
end record;
```

I've kinda been playing around with it some but can't make anything compile. Here are some things I've tried:

```
type My_Record(Disc : Positive) is
record
    A : Integer;
    B : Integer;
    C : Int_Array(1..(if Disc = 320 then 4 else 10));
    D : Int_Array(1..(if Disc = 320 then 2 else 4));
end record;
```

But this results in the error "discriminant in constraint must appear alone".

If I try:

```
type My_Record(Disc : Positive) is
record
    A : Integer;
    B : Integer;
    case Disc is
        when 320 =>
            C : Int_Array(1..4);
            D : Int_Array(1..2);
        when others =>
            C : Int_Array(1..10);
            D : Int_Array(1..4);
    end case;
end record;
```

The definitions of C and D conflict with each other. Is there some other technique I can use for this?

Comment: The basic rule for doing things that the language doesn't support directly is "Make it private".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the variables with `.C` and `.D` regardless of the variant, you could use accessor functions:

```
   type My_Record (IDisc : Positive) is record
      IA, IB : Integer;
      case Disc is
         when 320 =>
            C1 : aliased Int_Array (1 .. 4);
            D1 : aliased Int_Array (1 .. 2);
         when others =>
            C2 : aliased Int_Array (1 .. 10);
            D2 : aliased Int_Array (1 .. 4);
      end case;
   end record;

   type Int_Array_Accessor (Data : not null access all Int_Array) is
     limited null record with Implicit_Dereference => Data;
   function C (Object : in out My_Record) return Int_Array_Accessor is
     (Int_Array_Accessor'(if Object.Disc = 320 then
                          Object.C1'Access else Object.C2'Access));
   function D (Object : in out My_Record) return Int_Array_Accessor is
     (Int_Array_Accessor'(if Object.Disc = 320 then
                          Object.D1'Access else Object.D2'Access));
```

By using an accessor with `Implicit_Dereference`, you can assign values as if it was a record field.

Comment: Having record declaration private, that solution would allow to use C and D without any knowledge of C1, D1, C2, D2. Using Ada 2012 and later, if that record is tagged type, you may even have object.C notation and have it behave as field accessor.

Answer (score 2):

In the case statement use different variable names in each case. Your original examples contain a few syntax errors.

```
package foo is
   type Int_Array is array(Integer range <>) of Integer;
   type My_Record(Disc : Positive) is
      record
         A : Integer;
         B : Integer;
         case Disc is
         when 320 =>
            C : Int_Array(1..4);
            D : Int_Array(1..2);
         when others =>
            E : Int_Array(1..10);
            F : Int_Array(1..4);
         end case;
      end record;
end foo;
```